# iOS kills my background fetch process; creates unnecessary crash logs?

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm using the new background fetch mode in iOS 7, In my users' crash logs I'm seeing a lot of:

```
MyApp[11893] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x176afef0> identifier: Background Content Fetching (3281) process: MyApp[11893] permittedBackgroundDuration: 30.000000 reason: backgroundContentFetching owner pid:33 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownUI  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

I assume I'm getting this because my update is taking longer than the permitted 30 seconds and is therefore being killed by the system. There's nothing I can do do ensure the fetch takes <30sec, as it's obviously dependant on many external factors.

Now, this seems like pretty reasonable behaviour - desired, even - but does it need to be crashing and polluting the logs? Should I be monitoring the `[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining` and call my `completionHandler` early if I start to run low on time, or am I doing things correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crash log sounds reasonable since the app is being killed by the OS.

If you want to avoid the crash and fail gracefully, yes, monitoring the `backgroundTimeRemaining` sounds like a good solution.

Since you are not going to complete the operation in time in any case is better to terminate it yourself, instead of getting killed by the OS.

Comment: using a nstimer of 30 sec is also good... assuming '30 sec' won't change in the future..

Comment: @ErbenMo that an assumption I wouldn't do. `backgroundTimeRemaining` is there precisely for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a),

> your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the specified completion handler block

If you are downloading data using http or ftp you could look at using [NSURLSession and associated classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) to kick off the fetch and call the completion handler immediately, and then iOS will re-awaken your app when the download has finished.